# Edição de imagens em um crud

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, ejs

Eu tenho um `CRUD` de produtos o qual possui o nome, preço, descrição e 4 imagens para cada.
O adicionar, visualizar e deletar eu já consegui fazer. Mas a questão do editar está me pegando por conta da edição das imagens.
Eu uso a biblioteca multer para salvar e tratar a url da imagem. E já percebi que não consigo jogar no campo `type = "file"` essa url.

Eu queria jogar a url neste campo abaixo:

```
<input name="imagem1" type="file" required >
```

Qual seria a melhor estratégia para isso?

Comment: Por que não pode ser `type="text"`?

Comment: Porque estou pegando um arquivo, uma imagem do usuário

Answer (score 0):

Quando você está editando um campo de imagem, não faz sentido você tentar receber a imagem novamente.
Apenas ignore o campo no update, se não vier dados do input file.